# Android bypass Profile Proxy with restlet

Tags: java, android, http, proxy, restlet

I'm developing an application that must run on devices configured for a VPN Network. The network profile is configured with a proxy. The proxy allows the device exit from the VPN and navigate on internet.

My application must access a server in the intranet and mustn't use the proxy to access it. If the proxy is set the server is unreachable, if the proxy is not set internet is unreachable.

I need to access internet with all applications of the device, but my application must access to the server. So i configured the device network profile with the proxy but now i need to bypass the proxy using my application!

Have you any ideas?

PS: I use Restlet for the communication with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem simply using Java System Properties:

- http.proxyHost
- http.proxyPort

These values overrides android system proxy settings.

It works!